# Using multiple lists for a single recyclerview adapter in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm making a notes app that has 6 lists and 6 adapters for every list and users can add sections in every list and they can add items in the sections.. the problem is I'm using one adapter for the items in the sections and it's not working well.. sometimes it doesn't show the items and sometimes it adds items to another section

This is the sections' types

```
val text1: String, val text2: String, val text3: String, val text4: String, val id: Int, val list: MutableList<Pair<String, String>>
```

This is the items' adapter

```
package com.m.anwer.eldrasa

import com.m.anwer.eldrasa.Zholder

import com.m.anwer.eldrasa.Zinterface

import android.view.LayoutInflater

import android.view.View

import android.view.ViewGroup

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class Zadapter(private var items: MutableList<Pair<String, String>>, private val listener: Zinterface) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Zholder>() {

    

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) : Zholder {

        return Zholder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.zcst, parent, false))

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Zholder, position: Int) {

        val item = items[position]

        holder.tv1.text = item.first

        holder.tv2.text = item.second

        holder.crd.setOnClickListener { listener.onItemZ(position) }

        holder.btndel.setOnClickListener { listener.delItemZ(position) }

        holder.btnedit.setOnClickListener { listener.ediItemZ(position) }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return items.size

    }

    

    fun updateList(list: MutableList<Pair<String, String>>) {

        items.clear()

        items.addAll(list)

        notifyDataSetChanged()

    }

}
```

This is how I switch between lists

```
zadapter.updateList(list1[pos].list)
```

list1 is one of the 6 lists and list1[pos].list is a list I want to use for the adapter

For the adding function I'm sure about it and it works fine but as I said before sometimes it adds itmes to another sections or sections in another lists

I tried to clear the adapter's current list then before switch but didn't work